# How can I get a colored DOI link only, without the URL?

Tags: bibtex, doi

I am using the AMS Bibtex style. For example, I want the DOI to look like: `doi:10.1080/0....` with color. But I don't want the URL, only the colored DOI number with a link. Also, I want the references in numbered style, not in alphabetically. Please suggest a way to do this and/or required packages.

I used `{plainurl}` but it is showing an error like:

> Use of \sb doesn't match its definition. \do ...def ~}{\mathchar
> \number \mathcode `#1\sb {/}}\mathcode `#1=32768 \fi  l.10
>
> If you say, e.g., `\def\a1{...}', then you must always
> put `1' after `\a', since control sequence names are
> made up of letters only. The macro here has not been
> followed by the required stuff, so I'm ignoring it.

Comment: Your wish is unclear to me.  Do want just the DOI text coloured without a hyperlink?  Please add a small complete document showing how you use `plainurl`, cf. [minimal working example with bibliography (MWEB)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407)